# If $X$ has a density, then does $Y:=g(X)\cdot 1_{\{X>0\}}$? (No...?)

Tags: probability, integration, measure-theory, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I think there is a typo in my probability theory book's exercises. Probability Essentials by Jacod and Protter, exercise 11.9 says:

> Let $X$ have a density, and let $$Y=ce^{-\alpha X}1_{\{X>0\}}, \qquad (\alpha > 0, c>0).$$ Find $f_Y(y)$ in terms of $f_X.$ [Ans: $f_Y(y)=\frac{f_X\left(-\frac{1}{\alpha}\ln\left(\frac{y}{c}\right)\right)}{\alpha y}1_{(0,c)}(y).$]

I don't think $Y$ necessarily has a density. $F_Y(y)=\int 1_{\{ce^{-\alpha X}1_{\{X>0\}}\leq y\}} dP$. If $X$ takes nonpositive values with nonzero probability, won't $F_Y$ be discontinuous at 0?

Comment: Recall that the Laplace-Stieltjes transform (which for an absolutely continuous distribution is just a Laplace transform) of $X$ is $\mathbb E[e^{-sX}]$. This expression looks very similar...

Comment: Right, but we're cutting everything off for negative X with the indicator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are right. If $E\sim\mathrm{Exp}(1)$ is an exponential random variable, then choosing $X=-E$ yields a random variable with a density whereas $Y=0$ a.s. does not have a density.

One can show in general that if $\mathbb P(X\le0)>0$ then $Y$ does not have a density.